# Add RDFa using own RDF Schema

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, rdfa

I want to create an RDFS ontology describing some specific classes and properties. Then I want to add RDFa into HTML with the vocabulary I defined in RDFS. I know that we need to provide a URL to the vocabulary in RDFa, but I am not sure where to put my RDFS file in the web app or how to deploy the RDFS file.

When I add RDFa with schema.org, the HTML is like:

```html
  <div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
  <span property="name">Jane Doe</span>
  <img src="janedoe.jpg" property="image" alt="Photo of Jane Joe"/>
  <span property="jobTitle">Professor</span>
  <div property="address"  typeof="PostalAddress">
    <span property="streetAddress">
      20341 Whitworth Institute
      405 N. Whitworth
    </span>
    <span property="addressLocality">Seattle</span>,
    <span property="addressRegion">WA</span>
    <span property="postalCode">98052</span>
  </div>
  <span property="telephone">(425) 123-4567</span>
  <a href="mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu" property="email">
    jane-doe@xyz.edu</a>
  Jane's home page:
  <a href="http://www.janedoe.com" property="url">janedoe.com</a>
  Graduate students:
  <a href="http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html" property="colleague">
    Alice Jones</a>
  <a href="http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html" property="colleague">
    Bob Smith</a>
</div>
```

In the beginning of the HTML

```html
<div vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Person">
```

it states using the vocabulary Schema.org.

I want to ask how to use own RDFS. Also, how can I validate the RDFa is properly linked to my RDFS and written correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways how to host a vocabulary/ontology:

- hash namespace (e.g., `http://example.com/vocabulary#Person`)
- slash namespace (e.g., `http://example.com/vocabulary/Person`)

The W3C Working Group Note [*Best Practice Recipes for Publishing RDF Vocabularies*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-swbp-vocab-pub-20080828/) contains some [recipes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/NOTE-swbp-vocab-pub-20080828/#choosing), which illustrate example configurations.

Let’s assume that you go with a hash namespace, so that the complete vocabulary is contained in `http://example.com/my-voc`, and a class like "Person" would have the URI `http://example.com/my-voc#Person`.

Now you want to use classes/properties from your vocabulary in your RDFa. So let’s add a `prefix` for each vocabulary you want to use (you could also keep using `vocab` for a "default", prefix-less vocabulary, if you want to):

```html
<div prefix="schema: http://schema.org/ foo: http://example.com/my-voc#">
</div>
```

You can now use `schema:Person` for Schema.org’s `Person` class, and `foo:Person` for the `Person` class from your own vocabulary.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I am very confused that how to validate RDFa when using own RDFS?

Comment: @YichenHE: How do you validate your RDFa? It should make no difference which vocabulary you are using.